# Workbench Error no definition

Tags: c++, arm, stm32

En un proyecto en c++ para manejar un STM32F407 me encuentro con este error al compilar

```
   Linking 
   Error[Li005]: 
    no definition for "USBD_LL_Transmit" [referenced from STM32\Obj\usbd_cdc.o] 
   Error[Li005]: 
    no definition for "USBD_LL_PrepareReceive" [referenced from STM32\Obj\usbd_cdc.o] 
   Error while running Linker
```

El caso es que las dos funciones están declaradas en usbd_conf.h que esta en los includes.
¿Que puede dar este error?, ¿por que IAR no encuentra las funciones incluso estando definidas?

Comment: Esas funciones son parte de una librería? Asegúrate de enlazarla correctamente.

Comment: Si, son parte de las HAL Library, las correspondientes a la gestión del USB.  http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2015/08/hal-library-21-multi-purpose-usb-library-for-stm32fxxx/    Creo que están bien enlazadas, ¿Cómo lo compruebo?.

Comment: Por empezar, qué compilador tienes o cómo estás compilando el proyecto?